# Вычислить возраст и добавить в столбец age phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, дата

Есть таблица `student(birthday,age)`
В `birthday` заносятся данные из `input type="data"`
Как вычислить возраст студента и добавить в строку `age` в `student`?

Comment: ну так в чем проблема? 
$age = $today - $birthday
и INSERT в БД.

Comment: А зачем вам колонка age ? ее значение всегда можно посчитать и так в момент обращения. Какая у вас СУБД ? Функции для работы с датой  практически не стандартизированы и в каждой БД свои

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще как бы 1. Имея дату несложно считать возраст и как бы держать, дублирующие данные нехорошо. Но если вам очень надо возраст то DATEDIFF вам поможет а точнее где-то так **select DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(birstday,now())), ‘%Y’)+0 AS age** , а функцию update написать и колонку в phpmyadmin я думаю вы сами сможете